# Auto-comment model on migration in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I seem to recall that there was a plugin or Rake snippet that would put comments in various Model classes after running a migration?  It's a chore to have to look at db/migrate/X when I want to see which fields a given model has.

If not, I'll write one, of course. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be thinking of the Annotate Models plugin at:
http://repo.pragprog.com/svn/Public/plugins/annotate_models/

I believe that does exactly what you describe, although I haven't personally used it in a while, so can't vouch for its behaviour on more recent Rails versions.

Regards,
NeilS.

Comment: I used this plugin for a while but stopped also.

It doesn't really solve the problem (since you often have to check to see if the annotations are still accurate, which defeats the purpose of using them), and it adds a bunch of noise to your checkin that presumably has nothing to do with most of the files that you changed by re-annotating.

Just look at db/schema.rb, or if you want to solve this via overkill, figure out a way to make these annotations get dropped at checkin time *and* auto update during db:migrate. :)

Comment: I'll grab the source and write an update so that it updates on db:migrate; dropping at checkin isn't really an issue for me, though.

Comment: The latest version of the `annotate` gem does what you want (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4):

There is a school of thought that suggests you you shouldn't put attribute comments in the model as it breaks the principal of DRY. I won't argue the point. However, one real nice way of identifying attributes of the model is to simply type the Model name when you are in ./script/console

```
 > User
=> User(id: integer, loginname: string, password: string, fullname: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I always have ./script/console session open when developing Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain the [annotate gem](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) (which started life as that venerable plugin by Dave Thomas) and the latest version allows you to run

```
rails g annotate_models:install
```

which adds a rake file to your project. Afterwards, annotate will be executed whenever you run `rake db:migrate` (but only in development mode).

...currently this feature [seems to be broken](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/issues/97) :-(